# Multichannel audio input using Qt/Phonon

Tags: c++, qt, audio, audio-recording, phonon

My company is currently working on what could be called an audio analysis program which needs to process to multiple audio inputs (8 or so) in real time. This means that we need a framework that can handle multichannel audio interface devices that have up to 8 input channels. On top of this, the framework should be as portable as possible.  We actually started our development using Java but it ran into issues with the sound API.

When looking for alternate ways to do what we need, I started thinking about using C++ and Qt. I have some experience with both, but I've never done anything remotely similar (in any language for that matter)

Now, the question is, can Qt/Phonon handle audio interfaces/sound cards with over 2 input channels (assuming that the OS can see the devices just fine)? Would it dependent on the backend being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonon as no input function. it's for playback only if i'm right. 
 but if you want to process input audio you can use [QAudioInput](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qaudioinput.html#QAudioInput-2). I've used it with just one audio input but I think [this constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qaudioinput.html#QAudioInput-2) with the right [QAudioDeviceInfo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qaudiodeviceinfo.html) could do what you want.

Comment: Argh, I completely forgot that all input is done via Qt and not Phonon. Well, I figure I'll just hook up an audio interface and see what QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedChannelCounts() gives me. Thanks for the answer in any case.